# Android Ionic keyboard issue overlap when input field clicked but works fine when typing

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic on android devices, I met with some keyboard issues.

When I click the input field, the keyboard shows up, but overlap the input fields with the background not scrolling up, but when I try to type some word, the background will scroll normally.

How could I solve this problem？

In manifest, I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"`
and I did not use ionic keyboard plugin.

If I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"`, in each scenario, whether I click or type, it does not act normally.